# Where is the Kubernetes extensions API group in RHEL 7.2?

Tags: kubernetes, jobs, rhel7

I have a working RHEL 7.2 Kubernetes 1.2.0 installation.

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)

# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.0", GitCommit:"86327329213fed4af2661c5ae1e92f9956b24f55", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.0", GitCommit:"86327329213fed4af2661c5ae1e92f9956b24f55", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

I managed to deploy some workloads, simple Pods, RCs, Services work just fine.

I found that some components are missing from the basic installation, for example the dashboard was not deployed, so I deployed the canary version and I also had to setup manually the missing kube-system namespace.

I wanted to experiment with the [Job workload type](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/jobs/). However I can't get other [API groups](http://kubernetes.io/docs/api/#api-groups) working besides the basic v1.

```
# kubectl create -f job.yaml
error validating "job.yaml": error validating data: API version "batch/v1" isn't supported, only supports API versions ["v1" "extensions/v1beta1" "v1beta3"]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

trying with any of the listed extensions/v1beta1 or v1beta3 results in error as well:

```
# kubectl create -f job.yaml
error validating "job.yaml": error validating data: the server could not find the requested resource; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

The job object is the simplest example with the Pi calculation.

It seems that the extensions API is not compiled into the default RHEL7 RPM? Or is this something which could be deployed separately?

To build the cluster, I used [Red Hat's guide for installing Kubernetes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-enterprise-linux-atomic-host/7/getting-started-with-containers/chapter-3-creating-a-kubernetes-cluster-to-run-docker-formatted-container-images).

I think I will just rebuild my whole installation from scratch using the  [kubernetes.io docker (multi-node)](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/) way, but it would be greatly appreciated if anybody could shed some light on this, thank you!

Comment: Red Hat confirmed that they don't deliver currently these features as part of the binaries. I guess it makes sense not to include beta versions with their usual commitment to production-readiness.